# GCC Linker - Locate a section/constant at a specific address within the .text section

Tags: c, constants, linker-errors, memory-address, sections

I would like to locate a 32bit constant value at a specific address (0x080017FC) within the .text (code) section.

To be honest, when it comes to modifying the linker script to this extent I'm naïve and feel like I do not have a clue what to do.

I've modified my linker script to contain this new section (.systemid) within the .text section.

```
  .text :
  {    
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.systemid))
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH
```

To ensure it does not get optimized away, I used KEEP.

I then declared my constant in the new section `(.systemid)`. This is where I start to wonder what am I supposed to do. If `.systemid` was a section on its own, I would have declared the constant as follows:

```
const uint32_t __attribute__((used, section (".systemid"))) SYSTEM_ID_U32 = 0x11223344;
```

But since this is a section within a section, should it not be?:

```
uint32_t __attribute__((used, section (".text.systemid"))) SYSTEM_ID_U32 = 0x11223344;
```

So the linker will locate the constant at the beginning of the `.text section (0x000001A0)`. Great, it is inside the text section but not at the correct address. I would like to locate the constant at `0x08001F7C`.

To try and achieve this, I pass the following to the linker:

```
 -Wl,--section-start=.text.systemid=0x080017FC
```

Again I'm not sure if it should be `.systemid` or `.text.systemid`

Either way, it does not locate the constant at `0x080017FC`

How do I get my constant to be located at `0x080017FC` within the `.text` (code) section without any overlap errors?

Comment: `But since this is a section within a section, should it not be?` No. There is no section _within_ a section.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve], with a complete buildable program and complete linker script?

Comment: Why do you want it "within the .text section" anyway?  Normally if you want an object at a specific address, you give it its very own section.  If you're concerned that it should be executable, you can set that attribute for the new section; it's not inherently tied to `.text`.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is legacy code and I need to ensure that 4 bytes has been allocated at that address in the code space for firmware updates to work. The firmware updater replaces those 4 bytes with a legacy ID. It will overwrite my code with an ID.

Comment: Section names do not have structure. These are just strings. `.text.systemid` is a different section than `.text` and a different than `.systemid`. And, _you_ should not use sections names starting with a dot - they are for linkers. `any overlap errors?` What errors?

Comment: @KamilCuk he wants linker to flood the text section around this location, but linker does not do such magic. If you want to have value in the weird place and not to be overwritten by the linker youy need to sacrifice some memory

Comment: So I guess the real question then is, how do you ensure that no other section, such as `.text`, overlaps the address in question?  And as @0___________ says, you can't except by manually placing sections such that, based on their size, they don't conflict.

Comment: Where does `.text` currently start?  If at 0, is your code really larger than 128 MB such that it collides with this object?  If at `0x8000000`, then a simple solution is just to start it instead at `0x8002000` and accept that 8 KB will be wasted.  Then you don't really even need to place anything at `0x080017FC`; the firmware can write it without breaking anything, and if you need to read what it wrote, just cast and dereference a pointer.

Comment: If you really need that extra 8KB, then you can hand-write assembly for a section to be placed at `0x8000000`, and use the assembler to place padding.  Like, write about 6 KB worth of code, then something like `.zero (0x17fc - $)` `firmware_id: .zero 4 ` and then more code if you like.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work this way. There is no way I am aware of placing section at the particular address without problems from the linker if it is part of another section. Linker is quite a simple program and will not optimize the memory to avoid your location.

I use two methods:

1. Place this id at the end of the FLASH. You cant do this at the beginning as there is the vector table.

```
const uint32_t __attribute__((used, section (".systemid"))) SYSTEM_ID_U32 = 0x11223344;
```

Place after all other sections in FLASH (it can be the last section definition

```
  .systemid :
  {
    . = ORIGIN(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASH) - 4;
    KEEP(*(.systemid))
  } >FLASH
```

or

```
  .systemid ORIGIN(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASH) - 4:
  {
    KEEP(*(.systemid))
  } >FLASH
```